# Reference column name when a certain value appears in that column

Tags: excel

I have tried a few different formulas but I'm having no luck. Basically I want to reference the dates that have been marked in the relevant columns. below is my attempt to show columns and rows to indicate what i'm working with, and where the formula results should display.

E.g

```
 [     a       ][      b     ][     c    ][     d    ][   e    ][   f    ]
1| start date  ][  deadline  ][ 01/01/01 ][ 02/01/01 ][03/01/01][04/01/01]
------------------------------------------------------------
2|  result1    ][  result4   ][          ][    -     ][   x    ][        ]
------------------------------------------------------------
3|  result2    ][  result5   ][     -    ][     x    ][        ][        ]
-------------------------------------------------------------
4|  result3    ][  result6   ][          ][      -   ][   -    ][   x    ]
```

result1 should equal 02/01/01 because that is the name/date associated with the marker "-",

result2 should equal 01/01/01 because that is the name/date associated with the marker "-",

result3 should equal 02/01/01 because that is the name/date associated with the marker "-",

result4 should equal 03/01/01 because that is the name/date associated with the marker "x",

result5 should equal 02/01/01 because that is the name/date associated with the marker "x",

result6 should equal 04/01/01 because that is the name/date associated with the marker "x".

Really appreciate your help I have tried V and H lookups as well as Index

Tanya.

Comment: My table didn't work, but each bracket set is a cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use index and match, something like below:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$F$1,1,MATCH("x",C2:F2,0))
```

where x can be your a string in your case its "x" or "-".

Hope this helps

Comment: When there is no result it comes up with #N/A, is there an extension to the formula to make it say "done" or something?

Comment: yes you can use isna with if , sth like : =IF(ISNA(INDEX($C$1:$F$1,1,MATCH("x",C2:F2,0))),"done",INDEX($C$1:$F$1,1,MATCH("x",C2:F2,0)))

Comment: One request though , please format your questions properly when asking as while formatting your question i was able to understand your question properly. Thanks, please also upvote if you are satisfied with answer

Answer (score 0):

The following formula in cell A2:

```
=IF(C2="-",$C$1,IF(D2="-",$D$1,IF(E2="-",$E$1,IF(F2="-",$F$2,"1/1/00"))))
```

Likewise, the following in B2:

```
=IF(C2="x",$C$1,IF(D2="x",$D$1,IF(E2="x",$E$1,IF(F2="x",$F$1,"1/1/00"))))
```

Format A2 and B2 as dates.  Copy/paste the cells down columns A and B.  I believe that will give you what you want.  Note that I have inserted a moderately random value (Jan 1, 1900) for what happens when no - or x is found.  You'll want to substitute that with something reasonable.

Comment: It's displaying the "-" and "x" as the result not the date in the cells above it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, worked for me.  In any case, Pradeep's answer is clearly superior ;-).